# JetBrain or PyCharm like LaTeX IDE with vim plug-in

Tags: vim, vim-latex, ide

Does there exist JetBrain or PyCharm like LaTeX IDE with vim plug-in where you auto-complete for commands, etc. are supported? Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by an IDE with Vim plug-in? Do you want a separate IDE or do you want a Vim plug-in? For the latter, VimTeX https://github.com/lervag/vimtex does support command completion (among other features).

Comment: @WillieWong Maybe my questions wasn't clear enough; I'll modify my question to make it clearer. I meant.. I want to know 1) whether there exists IDE which provides JetBrain or PyCharm like convenient functionalities, such as, auto command complete, and if so, 2) does that support vi editor, if not 3) does that accept vi editor as plug-in? But I think you may have already answered my question. I'll check out VimTeX and will get back to you. Thx!!